# asp.net double buffering?

Tags: asp.net, refresh, double, buffering

How can I use double buffering in asp.net C#?

I want smthng like that : I dont want full page refresh when I click a button in a web page.. I think it can be solved with double buffering. When a button clicked for redirect a content page (button-in master page), current page will not go until the redirected page completely load in the background..

Can anybody help me, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

- [UpdatePanel control](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/)
- [UpdatePanel Control Overview](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx)
- [UpdatePanel tutorial ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/UpdatePanel-tutorial-ASP-NET-AJAX-AID281.aspx)
- [Using the ASP.NET UpdatePanel
  Control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/tutorials/UsingUpdatePanelMasterPages.aspx)

> The UpdatePanel control is probably
>   the most important control in the
>   ASP.NET AJAX package. It will AJAX'ify
>   controls contained within it, allowing
>   partial rendering of the area.

Comment: Take a look also at ASP.NET MVC and partial views which make doing partial updates a breeze, flexible and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Then don't use the postback model in provided in ASP.NET!  ASP.NET will cache some content on it's own, so some round trips will be faster, but the postback thing gets used by default all the time.

Using updatable controls, AJAX, or straight client-side scripting are all ways to avoid round trips. Which you use depends on what you need done on the page.